# How can I create a pdf with php?

Tags: php, pdf

I want to create a very simple pdf with php that will be downloaded when I load the the page.

This is my page `pdf.php`

```
<?php
$p = PDF_new();

if (PDF_begin_document($p, "", "") == 0) {
    die("Error: " . PDF_get_errmsg($p));
}

PDF_set_info($p, "Creator", "hallo.php");
PDF_set_info($p, "Author", "Rainer Schaaf");
PDF_set_info($p, "Title", "Hallo Welt (PHP)!");

PDF_begin_page_ext($p, 595, 842, "");

$font = PDF_load_font($p, "Helvetica-Bold", "winansi", "");

PDF_setfont($p, $font, 24.0);
PDF_set_text_pos($p, 50, 700);
PDF_show($p, "Hallo Welt!");
PDF_continue_text($p, "(sagt PHP)");
PDF_end_page_ext($p, "");

PDF_end_document($p, "");

$buf = PDF_get_buffer($p);
$len = strlen($buf);

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $len");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hallo.pdf");
print $buf;

PDF_delete($p);
?>
```

When I load `pdf.php` I get a blank page and nothing else happens. Did I forget anything?

Comment: You forgot to take a look into your http servers error log page where you can read what the actual issue is.

Comment: ah ok, the error is: `fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function PDF_new()`

Comment: Ah, ok, that is something you can start with, right? PHP does not offer some builtin function creating a PDF object, you need to load some library for that. Common alternatives are `tcpdf` or `fpdf`, others exist. Once you have installed and included that library (manually or automatically) you can go on.

Comment: Oh, I understand. So without an external library it won't work!

Comment: In theory it is possible with plain PDF, certainly once can theoretically create arbitrary binary data. but in practice you need a PDF implementation, PHP does not have such thing builtin.

Comment: @arkascha *"PHP does not offer some builtin function creating a PDF object"* - actually yes: http://php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php I.e. example: `$p = PDF_new();` but that might not be installed / available on their system. Which is where they got their code from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I never saw that old implementation installed anywhere.

Comment: @arkascha I don't even think it's on mine neither *lol*

Comment: wow the installation of tcpdf looks very complicated. It is needed to be installed on a unix system. I never did that, and have no idea how to do this. But if there is no other option I will try to learn it

Comment: I don't see why you need a unixoid system as a platform to use the `tcpdf` library. It is plain PHP.

Comment: Oh , ok. I was looking on this documentation http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-tcpdf/ and they are talking about installing TCPDF on a UNIX®-like system, so I was uncertain. But now I found this nice tutorial. And it seems to be not to hard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_NWOSB2daY

Comment: It is working! Thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step tutorial:

1. download tcpdf: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/
2. Put the downloaded folder `tcpdf`in the same folder where you have your `create-pdf.php`.

This is an example for the `create-pdf.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Creates an example PDF TEST document using TCPDF
 * @package com.tecnick.tcpdf
 * @abstract TCPDF - Example: Default Header and Footer
 * @author Nicola Asuni
 * @since 2008-03-04
 */

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
<h1>Welcome to <a href="http://www.tcpdf.org" style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#CC0000;color:black;">&nbsp;<span style="color:black;">TC</span><span style="color:white;">PDF</span>&nbsp;</a>!</h1>
<i>This is the first example of TCPDF library.</i>
<p>This text is printed using the <i>writeHTMLCell()</i> method but you can also use: <i>Multicell(), writeHTML(), Write(), Cell() and Text()</i>.</p>
<p>Please check the source code documentation and other examples for further information.</p>
<p style="color:#CC0000;">TO IMPROVE AND EXPAND TCPDF I NEED YOUR SUPPORT, PLEASE <a href="http://sourceforge.net/donate/index.php?group_id=128076">MAKE A DONATION!</a></p>
EOD;

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Other examples: https://tcpdf.org/examples/

Video Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_NWOSB2daY

Comment: I don't think this is needed. Stack isn't a personal blog.

Comment: I thought it is helpful for other people. Should I delete it?

Comment: What do you mean by personal. This is from the tcpdf documentation you suggested me

Comment: That's up to you. However, posting an answer for something that already exists isn't really considered as an answer, *per se*. If you get downvoted, it would **not** have come from me. Others who share my view on the "not a personal blog" may agree with what I said about that. The solution already exists in documentation. Unless you can show/prove what is truly unique to you that would make a difference from the documentation's example and could help future visitors, only then does it constitute as an answer. IMHO, it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, you are totally right. I just think, because there is no answer to my question per se. This is a kind of an answer. Because this is what you need to solve the problem. Maybe it is helpful for someone, who is like me :)